Text Reveal Effect using Geometry Nodes
how would I set up a Text Reveal as in the attached movie file using Blender Geometry nodes? I have no experience with geo nodes. It would be useful if the string of copy could be edited for different uses. Thanks

Your question is not really suitable for this site as it's really asking for a full tutorial. However you could probably modify this comprehensive tutorial about text effects using Geometry nodes and place your text behind a white plane so that it shows as it moves up behind it.

I would suggest either to learn GN, to use other features than GN, or to pay someone to do it.
